# Bad request 400 in Production because of static files

Tags: python, django, production-environment

I have a problem with static files in Production after upgrading to Django 1.11. Before everything was working fine and I assume that all the setup is correct except some parts which probably have changed in new version of Django.

To be more specific about the problem. I have static image on my index page. After update my Production server returns "Bad request 400" on index page.

If some configurations are required then I can post it. Any ideas how to solve it are welcome!

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.ru', 'mysite.ru']
```

Comment: Post your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: So you are using same domain in ALLOWED_HOSTS to access your app?

Comment: Check all answers from this. May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false

Comment: @L_S Yes, I am using it. As I wrote everything was working fine before upgrade so I don't think that the problem is in ALLOWED HOSTS. Also after commenting the line with static image website is running normally.

Comment: And what is the `src` of that static image inside the (probably) `img` element?

Comment: @nik_m good, question. Actually I cannot see it, because when I enable this image the only thing which I get from my server is BAD_REQUEST 400. I assume the src should be formed from STATIC_URL + path defined after static tag.

Comment: @L_S I have made an experiment and put * in ALLOWED_HOSTS. It didn't help.

Comment: Do this in the shell: `from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static` and then `url = static('path_to_img')`. What do you get?

Comment: Can you post your web server config ?

Comment: @nik_m I get Suspicios operation when I am trying to do it.

Comment: @L_S Do you mean Apache config?

Comment: @nik_m Thank you very much! Your hint was useful. After I have found there was suspicious operation on static file load I have found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647182/django-suspicious-operation-on-image-upload The problem was solved after removing the first slash after static tag.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov. Glad I could help! Happy coding then alexander :)

Comment: @nik_m thanks! The same to you!)